# Basic SQL: selecting AVG() values depending upon two columns

Tags: sql-server, average

I want to get `AVG` values, depending upon the values of two columns.

Here is my table example:

[image: Example]

And this is what I need to get:

[image: Required output]

I'm using that code to get required data but it gives me average for issue not issue and owner.

Here is my code;

```
select issue, owner, AVG(time) from myTable group by issue, owner
```

Any suggestion about that?

Comment: The given data and expected results do not agree and/or are not clearly correlated. Also, make sure to include data in-line, preferably as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
select issue, owner, avg(time) over() from mytable
```